# j2me + direct access to MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, java-me, windows-mobile

It is possible to access MS SQL Server from j2me directly without any webservices?
I'm new to Mobile programming, but I need to create a small application on Pocket PC (WinCe 5.0) with access to ms sql server via LAN.
I searched on google and found http://www.mobiforms.com/, i think this is what i can use, but it is nor free :(
Can you write step by step what to to in order to write java app with access to MS SQL and to deploy on WinCe 5.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that this is not possible yet to configure your mobile app on J2ME to connect to database and get the data directly. It might cause the portability issue in the application.

The best way to do is to use Web Service (JAX-RS, SOAP, etc).

Comment: Be the way, do you know free jre for windows ce?

Comment: I guess Insignia has a MIDP but am not sure if its free.